# Expand canvas to the left or upwards in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, canvas

I can expand the canvas to the right or downwards without a problem, but is it possible to expand it to the left or upwards? Of course I can just move the whole drawing to the right, but the problem is that guides will stay where they are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple method

1. Make sure Snapping is enabled, and Snap to Page Border is also enabled, then draw a rectangle to fit the page size. Snapping will help you get it exact.
2. Change to the Select Objects tool <kbd>S</kbd>, and scale the rectangle to the left by clicking and dragging on the centre left handle. Note: If you need an exact size you can enter the required width/height manually in the options along the top and then make sure you reposition it by snapping to the existing page.
3. With the rectangle still selected, hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> which will change the size of the page to the selection.
4. Finally delete the rectangle

Example

[image]

Comment: When I hit `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `R`, guides move to the left, so unfortunately this didn't work for me, although I remembered I used this method in the past (I don't remember if guides stayed where they were before). I have Inkscape 1.0.

Comment: It appeared guides must not be locked for this to work.

Comment: @Necronomicron yes my guides were unlocked.

Comment: OMG, such problems to just increase the canvas size in Inkscape...

Comment: @JānisElmeris - This is an old answer.  it's much easier now. In the current version of Inkscape 1.2+ you can actually edit the canvas size on-screen with the Create and Edit Document tool. It also now has multi-page support. Inkscape is always being improved, and it's hard to keep up with all the changes sometimes.

Comment: @BillyKerr I see. Well, on my Linux Mint app manager Inkscape 0.92 is the latest, so this is probably still the way to go for me. :)

Comment: @JānisElmeris -see https://inkscape.org/release/inkscape-1.2.1/gnulinux/ubuntu/ppa/dl/ or there is an appimage here: https://inkscape.org/release/inkscape-1.2.1/gnulinux/appimage/dl/